# Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am updating some code in Objective-C and need to convert from Swift 3 to a newer version. I am running into an error that I'm not sure what to do about. The code with error is

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
_managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

The managedObjectContext portion of the AppDelegate is

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

The error that I get says `Property 'managedObjectContext' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'`. I don't know Objective-C, I just needed to update some resource files and the rest of the app falls into place around them, so I really don't know how I can resolve this. Any tips on what to do? This line is repeated several times throughout the app.

Comment: `managedObjectModel` != `managedObjectContext`

Comment: Thanks @vadian, I copied the wrong code. It's updated now.

Comment: I recommend to delete the question

Comment: Why would I delete it? I have a problem that I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bridging headers are set correctly, then it is enough to make property `@objc` available as below

```
@objc lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```